Plug-in resource lookup failed, resource ("bifrostvisplugin","kChannelNiceName_radius") is not registered
I'm getting this error when I try to use Bifrost
// Error: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2025/scripts/others/getPluginResource.mel line 66: Plug-in resource lookup failed, resource ("bifrostvisplugin","kChannelNiceName_radius") is not registered
I downloaded and installed the new update but still have this issue
